# A Report: Complex SQL Query from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following tables which need to be used in this query:

I am only mentioning the relevant columns of below tables so that it will be sort and understandable.

--> item [with columns: Item_ID, ItemCode, ItemName etc...]

```
Item_ID   ItemCode      ItemName
---------------------------------------------
1         P_1           Flower Pots
2         P_2           Parkar Pen
3         P_3           xyz
4         P_4           Aero Pace
```

--> channelstores [with columns: Store_ID, StoreName etc...]

```
Store_ID    StoreName
---------------------------------
1           Amazon UK
2           Amazon US
3           eBay UK
4           eBay US
```

--> channel_A [with columns: Item_ID, Store_ID etc...]

```
Item_ID   Store_ID
---------------------
1         1
1         2
2         2
3         1
```

--> channel_B [with columns: Item_ID, Store_ID etc...]

```
Item_ID   Store_ID
-------------------
1         3
1         4
2         3
3         3
```

Tables channel_A and channel_B has Item_ID and Store_ID as foreign key from item and channelstores tables respectively.

Now, the problem is: I need a query which can give me result as: The list of all the items from item table with its channelstores, channel_A and channel_B relations as following result:

```
Item_ID   ItemCode    Amazon UK    Amazon US   eBay UK    eBay US
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1            P_1             True         True       True       True
2            P_2             False        True       True       False
3            P_3             True         False      True       False
4            P_4             False        False      False      False
```

I have used below query but having issue to get True/False values:

```
Declare @StoreName as nvarchar(Max)
Declare @StrQuery nvarchar(Max)
set @StoreName=(SELECT  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + '['+p1.[storename]+']' 
FROM channelstores p1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') )

set @StrQuery=
'select Item_ID,ProductCode, '+@StoreName+' from 
(select i.Item_ID,i.itemcode as ProductCode,1 as Value,'''' as ChannelStore from item as i 
) as x
pivot
(max(Value)
for ChannelStore in ('+@StoreName+'))p order by ProductCode'
EXEC(@StrQuery)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How many storeNames do you have ?

Comment: @M. Page, It is dynamic and in channelstores table. currently there are 4 but it may be increased.

Comment: So you probably need a pivot table. You might have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Hi @M.Page, I have already used PIVOT to get storenames as Columns but having issues to get True, False values:

Comment: I added the solution with question, but it is giving null instead of True/False as I have not used channel_A and channel_B tables to get values True if Items are in channel_A or channel_B tables otherwise False. This is exactly where I am not getting where these tables should be used.

Comment: Hi @M.Page, can you please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> > I am only mentioning the relevant columns of below tables so that it will be sort and understandable. <<

Then we need the keys and constraints; that means DDL of some kind. Is the “item_code” like a UPC, EAN or other industry standard code? We have no idea. But that sequential “item_id” looks useless; did someone accidentally put an IDENTITY column on the table? We need that skeleton!

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(upc CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 item_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Channel_Stores
(store_id CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 store_name  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL);
```

Because you were rude, we also have to guess on the redundant tables.

-- wrong!

```
CREATE TABLE Channel_A 
(upc CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   REFERENCES Items(upc),
 store_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
   REFERENCES Channel_Stores(store_id),
 PRIMARY KEY (upc, store_id));
```

-- wrong!

```
CREATE TABLE Channel_B
(upc CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   REFERENCES Items(upc),
 store_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
   REFERENCES Channel_Stores(store_id),
 PRIMARY KEY (upc, store_id));
```

> > Tables Channel_A and Channel_B has upc and store_id as foreign key from Items and Channel_Stores tables respectively. <<

This design error is called “attribute splitting” and we do not do it. Would you have “male_Personnel” and “Female_Personnel” tables in a schema? No! It would be “Personnel” in a valid ISO-11179 schema.

You do not know what a normalized table is! This is why you are repairing your errors in dynamic SQL. This table has all your information that you will need to pass to a presentation layer.

```
CREATE TABLE Channels 
(upc CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   REFERENCES Items(upc),
 store_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
   REFERENCES Channel_Stores(store_id),
 channel_name CHAR(1) NOT NULL
   CHECK (Channel_name IN ('A', 'B')),
 PRIMARY KEY (upc, store_id, Channel_name));
```

So simply! So portable!

> > Now, the problem is: I need a query which can give me result as: The list of all the items from Items with its Channel_Stores, Channel_A and Channel_B relations as following result: <<

You might, but a SQL programmer would do this with a report tool. Nothing here is SQL.

We do not use assembly language bit flags in RDBMS.

We avoid proprietary code so that we can port the programs to the next release or to another SQL.

We do not mix XML or other programming languages in a query or a schema. It destroys performance and makes maintaining the code a bitch.

`SELECT DISTINCT` shows that the design flaws in the schema and the query have caused redundancy in the results.

We do not use local variables in SQL; this is a declarative language.

The only things to make this worse would be dynamic SQL to violate **First Normal Form** and then you did that!